# The length of the queue name in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

Help with a question. What is the maximum length of the queue name can have ActiveMQ? Is there a virtual queue ActiveMQ (e.g., zzz.ddd.qqq.tttt.eee ==> Q1). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMS doesnt specify restriction on length of queue names,but the number of bytes that it holds can be restricted.

Comment: Understood, thank) Is there support for virtual queues in ActiveMQ?

Comment: In documentation I could only find virtual topics,which can internally use queues.